# How to create backup from symbolic links?

Tags: tar, symlink

I have a directory with symbolic links to other directories. I want to archive the symbolic links, not as links but as archives containing the files of directories they refer to, using tar command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use the `-h` tar option. From the man page:

```
-h, --dereference
    don't archive symlinks; archive the files they point to
```

Comment: If I have /sym1 points to /backups and /sym2 points to /backups, then I run `tar -hcf file.tar /sym1 /sym2` will I get /backups twice?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez `-L` counts files once, `-l` multiple times. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82477/105615).

Comment: the order of options matters. ie `tar -czfvh` will fail `tar -hczfv` will work

Answer (score 3):

If the links are all in the root directory you can have the shell dereference them and pass to tar as arguments. For example if you  have /backup/source/a and /backup/source/b, both of which are symlinks pointing to the real directory, something like the following would work

```
tar -cf /path/to/backup.tar /backup/source/*/
```

Comment: Doesn't work here. Seems like `tar -cf /path/to/backup.tar /backup/source/a/` alone doesn't even work when `a` is a symlink.