# Behavior of `du` command with `-L` flag

Tags: symlink, disk-usage, coreutils

I've noticed a strange behavior with `du` command when it's used with `-L` command line option.

I'm using Slackware 14 and Coreutils 8.19.

To reproduce the strange behavior, create two folders:

```
mkdir foo
mkdir bar
```

Create a file inside one of the folder:

`perl -e 'print "A"x10000' > foo/text`

And a symlink in the other folder:

`ln -s ../foo/text bar/text`

Now, if you type:

`du -h -L bar`

You'll get:

`16k   bar`

Since the symlink was dereferenced. But if you type:

`du -h -L *`

You'll get:

```
16K     foo
4.0K    bar
```

And the symlink will not be dereferenced. Am I missing something?

Comment: it seems `du` wants to play clever here, but if you run `df -a -L bar foo` the output is very wrong (counting the 16K in bar leaving foo empty).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default, `du` will only count each file once if it is linked to multiple times. If you run `du -L bar` it will count the file because it only reaches it once. However, if you run `du -L *` it will only count it the first time it sees it. For example:

```
$ du -L foo bar
16K     foo
4.0K    bar

$ du -L bar foo
16K     bar
4.0K    foo
```

Notice that swapping the order of the arguments changes which folder gets reported as 16K.

You can force `du` to count the file twice by passing the `-l` parameter.

Edit:

Symbolic links are a special kind of file, and an extra step is needed to follow the link. `du` will not follow symbolic links unless the `-L` option is enabled.

A hard link on the other hand, is basically one file existing in two (or more) folders. `du` presumably tracks which files it has seen by inode number to avoid counting these twice. `-l` disables this behaviour.

So, with just `-L`, it will follow the symbolic link, but if the target file has an inode number it has already seen it will not be re-counted. With just `-l` it will count duplicate hard links, but will not follow symbolic links.

If you use `-l` and `-L` together, it will both follow the symbolic links, and also allow counting the target file(s) more than once.

Comment: Thank you. This works. However I would love to have some extra explanation. On man page, I read that `-l` does `count sizes many times if hard linked`, but here I'm working with symlink. Moreover, `-l` alone doesn't solve the problem, while if I use both `-l` and `-L` it counts the size properly.

Comment: @Zagorax Yeah, the man page is a little unclear on how `-l` and `-L` interact. The explanation got a bit too long for a comment, so I've updated my answer.